# Migrating repositories into Github from Stash/Gitlab

Tags: git, github, migration, metadata, settings

I have repositories hosted in Stash and Gitlab but would like to consolidate them to Github.

I am clear on how to move the the Git repositories themselves using `git clone --bare` and `git push --mirror`.

My question is about preserving the additional info related to these repos (e.g. pull requests, user permissions, hooks) to minimize the burden for the users having to reconfigure the newly migrated repos. Is there any existing tool to assist w/ such tasks.

The **blocker right now** is I don't have a way to migrate the fork relationship between the different repos. I would be happy if someone could describe a manual procedure to do that.

For example, say, I have a repo A in Stash, and A' is forked from A. Once I migrate A and A' to Github using the `git clone --bare` and `git push --mirror`, I have 2 unrelated repos. How can I make the new A' a fork of the new A?

Any pointer would be very helpful